# Git error remote: Empty password

Tags: git, bash, github, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone my git repo from bitbucket, and when I enter this command:

```
git clone https://naor_shoyhat@bitbucket.org/naor_shoyhat/hello-world.git
```

The bash then prompts me a window with areas to enter username and password.

I enter them and then I receive this error:

```
remote: Empty password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://naor_shoyhat@bitbucket.org/naor_shoyhat/hello-world.git/'
```

Comment: Where to run this command? In a bash shell? As I do in a bash shell it asks me only for the password because the username is already specified. Just type it in and hit enter.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this error lately. I'm using token authentication over Smartgit and I have to create a new token every couple of hours

Answer (score 100):

I'm using  git(2.12.2) 64-bit on Windows 10. My solution is simply close the login window which you have to type account and password, and a SSh window will pop out, then you type your password.

Comment: That helped. Seems it is an issue with the Git Credential Manager for Windows.

Comment: Wooow! I've never thought closing the credential manager pop-up window. You are awesome man, Thanks!

Comment: how can something as important as login be broken?

Comment: Strange fix but it works. If you click _cancel_ on the first time you get asked for a password you will get a window with the exact same appearance, just type your correct password and it should work. Thanks [Shin-Bang Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7791001/shin-bang-tsai)

Comment: Can't believe it - but it worked... I wasted like an hour on this

Comment: 30 mins ago, "it doesn't work, But why?". Me after seeing this solution, "it works, But why?" OMG

Answer (score 21):

I know my answer is very late. But I am going to explain to fix this problem on windows step by step. After upgrading SourceTree version 2.1.10, we can see like that.

SourceTree stores credentials in the Windows credential manager. To see and remove them, do the following:

1. Click on User Accounts in Control Panel.
2. In the left-hand list of links, click Manage Your Credentials.
3. When the Manage Your Credential page opens, it shows your Web Credentials.
    Click on the "**Windows Credentials**" button.
   [image]
4. In the list(Windows Credentials), look for entries that start with "git:http". Remove these entries.
5. And Please delete a file - C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\passwd
6. Source tree app re-open and work on this. If the app needs password, you can input.

All done. Hope to help you.

Comment: I added my account manually here without deleting anything and it worked. Thank you though

Answer (score 13):

You can try:

```
git clone https://naor_shoyhat:<password>@bitbucket.org/naor_shoyhat/hello-world.git
```

It worked for me in a pinch, but I do agree that it is not the best solution.

Comment: This worked for me too, but my password is now in plain text in the `.git/config` file

Answer (score 6):

If a pop up window ask for username and password close it, then introduce the password in the commandline.

It seems that is a bug on windows that sends an empty password to bitbucket. I use windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options->Git-> Update Embedded Git.

I did have to do this twice because there were issues extracting the first download.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which operating system you're using but in Windows there was a bug in the Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM), v1.9, which I believe was bundled with git v2.12.1 for Windows.

It resulted in a "remote: empty password" error when trying to authenticate to BitBucket.

The issue was fixed in version 1.10 of GCM.  The latest GCM installer can be found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

The details of the issue can be found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/399  The issue was raised on 24 March 2017, roughly about the time you started seeing your authentication problem.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall git for windows, thats worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Git **v2.12.2.2** released on 2017-04-05 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried all the possibilities and the problem persists, try this:

1. Close SourceTree
2. Click on User Accounts in Control Panel.
3. In the left-hand list of links, click Manage Your Credentials.
4. When the Manage Your Credential page opens, it shows your Web
   Credentials. Click on the "**Windows Credentials**" button.
5. In the list (Windows credentials), look for entries that relate to
   *SourceTree*. Remove all these entries. ***Be very careful in this step.***
6. And Please delete this folder: - C:\Users\AppData\Local\Atlassian

   *If you can not delete, restart your computer*
7. Uninstall SourceTree
8. Install SourceTree again

Note that the *location of the Git* installation may influence this procedure.

That was the only method that works for me. I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

This issue mentioned in link and comments in that - remove password file solved this problem for me

[reference](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7739)