# After updating SourceTree to version 2.1.10.0 - I started getting Git error "remote: Empty password"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

After updating SourceTree to version 2.1.10.0 - I started getting Git error "remote: Empty password" on each "pull" / "fetch" / ... actions.

The solution that worked for me was:
removing the **user name** from the repository URL:

in SourceTree - "Repository" --> "Repository Settings" --> edit --> remove your user name from the URL / Path section

Comment: Where is your code hosted? Does the host support SSH connection?

Comment: same issue here, I'm using bitbucket cloud

Comment: stumbled here, the first answer solved my issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100120/git-error-remote-empty-password

Comment: Already I did a post before. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855411/5834254